# Xcode unit test scenario with objc_sync_ functions

Tags: xcode, multithreading, unit-testing, swift2, xctest

I have a class `MyClass` like the following:

```
public class MyClass {
    private var syncObject = NSObject()

    public func myMethod(timeout: NSTimeInterval) -> AnyObject? {
        var obj: AnyObject? = nil
        objc_sync_enter(self.elementsSyncObject)
        if self.count > 0 {
            //obj = ... 
        }
        objc_sync_exit(self.elementsSyncObject)
        if obj != nil {
            return obj
        }
        let beginWaitDate = NSDate()
        objc_sync_enter(self.elementsSyncObject)
        if NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(beginWaitDate) <= timeout && self.count > 0 {
            //obj = ...
        }
        objc_sync_exit(self.elementsSyncObject)
        return obj
    }
}
```

The purpose of this function is to lock the object (to be thread safe) and retrieve something if it's available. But when it isn't, the function releases the lock, to give other waiting threads a chance to lock it, then tries to lock again and retrieve something again, but not if too much time passed waiting for this second lock.

The function seems to work fine. 
But, I'd like to test it thoroughly, in a XCTest.

What I manage to do is the following test:

```
func testAsync() {
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Desc")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        XCTAssertNotNil(myObject.myMethod(2))
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    myObject.myLongRunningMethod() // <-- method that is locking the same object and is measured to be running for more than 4 seconds
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10, handler: nil)
}
```

But I can't guarantee that the lock from `myLongRunningMethod` can occur 'between' the `myMethod` ones.

Any ideas, guys?